# Query Param - Replacing + by blank in golang

Tags: go, urlencode, query-string

I am using golang

```
func (ph *testHandler) GetData() gin.HandlerFunc {
    return func(ctx *gin.Context) {
        params := ctx.Request.URL.Query()
        search = strings.TrimSpace(params.Get("data"))
   } 
}
```

here I  am passing 'test+test' in url but I am getting 'test test'

How can I do query parsing in golang

Comment: The plus sign corresponds to a URL-encoded ASCII space. If you want to obtain `"test+test"` in the backend, you should percent-encode the plus sign in the value of the URL's query param: `test%2Btest`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The browsers treats `+` and `%20` signs in URL as space character so `test+test` in query parameter will have value `test test`.
To prevent this you have to manually add URL encoded value of `+` character literal in the URL - `https://example.com?data=test%2Btest`

For other URL encoded values see [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.ASP).

Answer (score 3):

If you look at the source

```
func (u *URL) Query() Values {
        v, _ := ParseQuery(u.RawQuery)
        return v
}
```

Calls ParseQuery which calls unescape in the "encodeQueryComponent" mode
as part of the things it does.

this code fragment is relevant

```
            case '+':
                    if mode == encodeQueryComponent {
                            t.WriteByte(' ')
                    } else {
                            t.WriteByte('+')
                    }
```

this is simply [RFC compliant parsing,](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7230) it's normal, the behaviour
you are seeing is expected

see https://cs.opensource.google/go/go/+/refs/tags/go1.16.6:src/net/url/url.go;drc=refs%2Ftags%2Fgo1.16.6;l=182

Comment: If this is RFC complaint parsing, why does every other language (python, JS, etc) not convert `+` to space when decoding urls? See, i.e. `unquote("+")` (python), `unescape("+")` (JS) Does that mean python and JS are *not* RFC complaint?

Answer (score 1):

The plus sign in the value of your query parameter is actually an URL-encoded ASCII space. If you want to obtain `"test+test"` in the backend, you should percent-encode the plus sign in the value of the URL's query param: `test%2Btest`.

Some minimal server code to fix ideas:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net/http"
)

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", handle)
    if err := http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}

func handle(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    data := r.URL.Query().Get("data")
    w.Header().Set("Content-type", "text/plain")
    fmt.Fprint(w, data)
}
```

Results:

- `http://localhost:8080/?data=test+test` prints `test test`, whereas
- `http://localhost:8080/?data=test%2Btest` prints `test+test`.